# GA funnel tracking using cross-domains and regex

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, goal-tracking, cross-platform

I have been using funnels to track people going from a store page to our thank_you page successfully, these funnels are from one domain and is only step1-->goal.

I have become completely stumped because I have setup cross-domain across all our websites in order to setup a funnel tracking the higher up steps. Although it doesn't want to convert when going from one domain to another, it just considers them as exiting at the first step.

I don't believe it to be a regex issue because I have tested the regex and they all match up with my dynamic url parameters.

The way I have my funnel setup is shown below:

```
Step1 (required): www\.landingPage\.com\/broadcast(.*)

Step2: www\.storePage\.com\/store\/xqDmoeuw(.*)

Goal: www\.storePage\.com\/thank_you\/hA1fx5m6\/(.*)
```

I have gone through the funnels by sending test traffic and trying to get them to convert but it just won't budge. I am currently using Google Tag Manager to collect my tracking data under the UA tracking code.

If anyone has any insight to cross-domain funnels or see any problems with my regex please I'll read any info I can find. Using free GA its been a pain having to wait up to 24hrs to see a change.

Comment: Did you also have a filter set up to include the hostname for all your hits? If not, then that could be why you aren't seeing conversions.

Comment: Yes I have a filter set up to see the hostname, I followed the documentation from google. Although I did find a [forum post](http://www.highrankings.com/forum/index.php/topic/44578-setting-up-goals-and-funnels-when-doing-cross-domain-tracking/) from someone with a similar problem, nobody replied but they suggested removing the hostname in the steps as google doesn't track that, only the request uri. So I made that change and will wait to see the results.

Comment: Hmm.. if you include the hostname in your filters, then it should follow that you would also need them in your goals (at least in my experience). You could do a wild card in front of all your steps and test out that way.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't GA say to use `/thank-you.html` instead of `http://www.example.com/thank-you.html` when configuring goal steps?

I think that might be what the hostname comments above are touching on.

You should be able to see some conversion data via Real Time analytics without having to wait 24 hours.

Have you tried recording your tags with Tag Assistant or the GTM debug setting?

I'd also double check all your GTM settings for cross-domain tracking like `allowLinker` and `Auto Link Domains`

I've always found [this article](https://www.optimizesmart.com/cross-domain-tracking-in-google-tag-manager/) pretty useful when having problems with GTM and cross-domain tracking.

Hope it helps.